$\mathbb{C}^*$-action on moduli space of Higgs bundles
Let $M_{r,d}$ be the moduli space of semistable Higgs bundles of rank $r$ and degree $d$ over a compact Riemann surface. Over $M_{r,d}$ we have a $\mathbb{C}^*$-action $$t \cdot (E,\phi)=(E, t \phi). $$
It is a known fact that for every $(E,\phi) \in M_{r,d}$, it exists the limit $\lim_{t \to 0}t \cdot (E,\phi)$. Inside $M_{r,d}$ we have the open locus $M^s_{r,d}$ of stable Higgs bundles of fixed rank and degree.
Is it true that taking a limit of a stable Higgs bundle we are still in the stable locus?

Isn't this limit just $E$ equipped with the zero Higgs field? in the case I think the answer is no as the underlying vector bundle of a stable Higgs bundle need not be stable.

In general the limit is not just $E$ with zero Higgs field, since as you said $E$ is not necessarily semistable. The existence of the limit is deduced from the properness of the Hitchin fibration

The answer is “no” in general. Let $X$ be a compact Riemann surface of genus at least $2$, and consider a rank $2$ Higgs bundle $(E, \theta)$ with $E$ a trivial bundle of rank $2$ and $\theta$ a generic traceless matrix of $1$-forms. I claim $(E, \theta)$ is stable. This suffices, since the limit in this case is the (strictly semistable) trivial bundle, with the zero Higgs field.
To see stability, it suffice to show that there is no trivial subbundle of $E$ preserved by $\theta$. This is impossible if e.g. the spectral curve is smooth and irreducible, which occurs if $\det \theta$ has simple zeroes, which is generically the case. (For example, one can take $\theta$ to have diagonal entries zero and off-diagonal entries two $1$-forms with distinct simple zeroes.)

(Sorry for the brief response, I’m typing on my phone.) The main point of the second paragraph is that a line subbundle of degree zero preserved by the Higgs field would give rise to a section to the (degree 2) spectral curve, which is impossible if it’s integral.

Very good answer, thank you!

@TommasoScognamiglio — my pleasure!
